# Как добавить программу в автозагрузку или в планировщик задач через .bat?

Tags: windows, администрирование

Добрый день.Есть очень интересная задача, но ни как не могу ее решить.

**Суть в чем**:

**1.** Есть компьютер с 2мя учетными записями (Админ и Юзер).

**2.** Админ имеет права адмистратора.

**3.** Юзер не имеет прав администратора. (Соответственно, если что-то запустить что-то от Имени админа, нужно вводить пароль от учетки Админа)

**4.** Есть одна программа, которая должна разово запускаться при входе в систему Юзером.

**Вопрос**: Как запускать программу при входе в систему?
- Вы скажете, добавить в планировщик задач или автозагрузку.

**Давайте рассмотрим вариант с планировщиком задач**. Так просто запустить без админ прав - не получится, нужны обязательно права. ОК. Делаем .bat файл и прописываем:

```
md "%appdata%\Lbama"
copy Lbama.exe "%appdata%\Lbama"
copy start.VBS "%appdata%\Lbama"
SCHTASKS /Create /ru "SYSTEM" /v1 /SC ONSTART /TN Lbama/TR "\"%appdata%\Lbama\start.VBS""
```

В start.VBS прописан код который запускает программу в фоне (не суть важно).

Если бы мы работали под админом - все было бы окей, задачка создалась. Но раз мы работаем под Юзером, и запустим задачу от имени админа, то у админа создастся эта задача, а у нас НЕТ. Соответственно, при входе в систему, у юзера ничего не запустится а у админа - запустится.

**Теперь перейдем ко вторую варианту, через автозагрузку.**
На просторах интернета пишут, что можно добавить в реестр и будет тебе счастье, хорошо, пробуем:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Lbama /t REG_SZ /d "appdata%\Lbama\Lbama.exe" /f
```

В итоге, получаем черный экран при входе под любой учеткой. И это так просто не вылечить. Быстрее было винду накатить новую.

Теперь соответственно вопрос, что я делаю не так? Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: А разве в планировщики задач нельзя указать учетку от которой запускать задание? Можно указать там админ учетку и батник вызовется с максимальными правами.

Comment: Можно, но названия учеток на разных компьютерах - разные

Comment: машины, судя по всему, не в домене. Плохо. Вообще подобная задача элементарно решается на уровне доменных политик, но если единого домена нет, то только индивидуально на каждой машине. Либо поднимать домен и не мучиться